# Azure Mobile App and Xamarin trying to insert 1:1 related entities to the database

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I have two objects GiftBasket and Gift

GiftBasket.cs

```
public class GiftBasket:EntityData
{
    public string MerchantId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public bool IsRedeemed { get; set; }

    public Gift Gift { get; set; }
}
```

Gift.cs

```
public class Gift: EntityData
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to inset new GiftBasket into the database

My Client-side code

Manager.cs

```
public async Task InsertGiftBasketAsync(GiftBasket giftBasket)
        {
            try
            {
                await giftBasketTable.InsertAsync(giftBasket);
            }
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Invalid sync operation: {0}", new[] { msioe.Message });

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Sync error: {0}", new[] { e.Message });
            }
        }
```

My code inside my page :

```
GiftBasket giftBasket = new GiftBasket
{
Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
MerchantId = Wallet.MerchantId,
UserId = Wallet.UserId,
Gift = Gifts.ElementAt(2).Gift,
Source = "Scratch",
IsRedeemed = false
};
await manager.InsertGiftBasketAsync(giftBasket);
```

When I try this using my mobile app I Get this error :

```
[0:] Invalid sync operation: The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)
```

When I try to add a new object manually using Postman I get this error  :

```
"message": "The operation failed with the following error: 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Gift_Id', table 'nojoom_db.dbo.GiftBaskets'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.'."
```

What Am I doing Wrong ? 
If I Edited my GiftBasket Model and removed the relationship with Gift and made it like this

```
public string Gift_Id { get; set; }
```

the insert works fine , but I sacrifice getting related data for gift in one API call .

Please note that GiftBasket is a new entry to the database but Gift inside it is already in the database in Gift table , I am not trying to insert new both.

**Update**

I changed my Models to this :

```
 public class GiftBasket:EntityData
    {
        public string MerchantId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public bool IsRedeemed { get; set; }

        public string GiftId { get; set; }
        public virtual Gift Gift { get; set; }

    }
```

and

```
  public class Gift: EntityData
    {
        public Gift()
        {
            GiftBaskets = new List<GiftBasket>();

        }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<GiftBasket> GiftBaskets { get; set; }

    }
```

which means I implemented One to many relationship which makes sense because one gift basket have many gifts .

But what If I wanted One to One relationship ? is this how to implement ?

```
 public class GiftBasket:EntityData
    {
        public string MerchantId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public bool IsRedeemed { get; set; }

        public string GiftId { get; set; }
        public virtual Gift Gift { get; set; }

    }

 public class Gift: EntityData
        {

            public int Value { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }

            public virtual GiftBasket GiftBasket { get; set; }

        }
```

when i do this , i get this error after calling GET

```
"Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types '****.DataObjects.GiftBasket' and '****.DataObjects.Gift'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."
```

when i add `[ForeignKey("GiftId")]`in giftbasket i get this error

```
"The property 'GiftId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type."
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted properly with postman? (Including all parameters)
It sounds as if you may have forgotten the ID while using Postman, and therefore not received a very helpful error.

Comment: You will, however, want to use `string gift_Id { get; set;}` - this is the correct thing to do. Don't write the object back.

Comment: @Bejasc I updated my Question , it works now that I implemented One to many . but not sure how to implement one to one .

Comment: @Bejasc so in the insert statment I set only the GiftId but not the entire Gift object that have id inside it ?

Comment: Check the example in the link : https://medium.com/@yostane/data-persistence-in-xamarin-using-entity-framework-core-e3a58bdee9d1

Answer (score 0):

Azure Mobile Apps assumes that each table is independent.  It does not handle joins.

You do the joins on the client side yourself, either using LINQ against the offline tables or using a direct SQLite command through the SQLiteStore object that you created.

Another way to do it is to "flatten" the object model on the client (which - since it's 1:1, should not be an issue), so you just have a GiftBasket (and no Gift), then you separate the request on the service side (updating two EF models when you submit the request, or combining two EF models on a query).